# Git: fatal: Cannot lstat '.README.swp': Permission denied

Tags: git

Seems, that I created by mistake a file .README.swp. (actually, by using command `vim README`). 
So, now I have:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .README.swp

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

When I'm trying to use command: `git clean -f` I have the following message:
fatal: Cannot lstat '.README.swp': Permission denied

How can I delete it then?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Um, `rm .README.swp`? Without git. Try quitting vim first, if that doesn't work, too.

Comment: I have `.*.sw?` in my `.git_ignore` to prevent these messages from being shown.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably either a lock on this file, or it has been created by another user (`root` perhaps).

Anyway, quit any application that might use it (probably just an instance of vim), and if it doesn't work, you may try running the clean command as root.

Comment: Thanks for response!
Okay, vim was closed at that time, didn't find any active application which used it. I solved the problem by computer reboot. Weird..

Answer (score 0):

Due to windiff or any similar process, it does not quit automatically.
you need to execute ps command to know running processes.
And the one with the pid of running process that might be blocking you.

Execute command:

```sh
kill -9 pid

clean -f
```

This should do your task.. all the best..

Answer (score 0):

sometimes vm must be running and prevents to delete the git .swp files as Boldewyn suggested above. Check as below and stop it. you should be now able to delete files.

c:>Powershell Get-Process -Name vm

c:>Powershell Stop-Process -Name vm